# LXC containers act differently on difrent servers

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, drupal, lxc, containers

I have two physical servers A and B. I wanted to upgrade them from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.

Here is my current setup (if I'm left out any info here, let me know and I'll add it):

Server A:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- ext4 on RAID and LVM
- lxc 0.75

Server B:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- btrfs in raid1
- lxc 1.04

Both servers are on the same vlan, and containers are on the same network.

**Now for the weird part.**

I have one Debian container running apache2 and drupal web page.

When I move this container from server A to server B, the web page gets broken. I transfered the container from A to B with the command

```
# this works (I think) and it's just so I can get sudo access 
# without allowing root ssh login

# --numeric-ids is here so the ownership remains the same inside the container
# without name mapping - user1 with id 1005 on server A, and id 1002 on server B

rsync -zavP --numeric-ids -e "ssh" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" A:/lxc/container B:/lxc/
```

So I think everything should be the same. But it's not.

Nov If I'm running the container on Server A, there is request for (theme **kanji**)

```
site.com/sites/all/themes/kanji/sf/js/superfish.js
```

When I moved the container to server B, the same requst looks like (theme **bober**)
This gets a 404 error, since it doesn't exist and the whole website looks broken.

```
site.com/sites/all/themes/bober/sf/js/superfish.js
```

*Now I don't want to just fix the problem in drupal, because if there is something different, there might be something else wrong too, something I haven't noticed yet. I am also worried about all the other containers I've moved*

Comment: Are you trying to say that something is altering URLs?

Comment: No, I am saying that that's the differenc I notice when copying containers from one pc to another.